# Rubik's cube 4x4x4

Tags: rubiks-cube

[image: Rubic's cube 4x4x4]

I have only two sides that are not right but the other two are right... everything but that has done. How do I complete this 4x4x4 Rubik's cube?

Comment: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/413/4x4x4-rubiks-cube-strategy?rq=1

Comment: Can you show us the other sides so we know which face has which colour?

Comment: If you're saying everything is right apart from those two corner cubelets, I don't believe you. The near-top-right one has to go in the green/white/red corner, and the near-top-left corner (the other one that we can see is wrong) is green/yellow/something. I expect red is opposite orange and white is opposite yellow, and the near-bottom-left corner is also wrong. So you need a move to cycle *three* corners, not *two*.

Comment: I bet you can adapt a three-corner cycle from the 3x3x3 cube to do the equivalent job on the 4x4x4.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil It looks like a standard cube, so white should be opposite yellow, blue opposite green and red opposite orange.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan true, it has to be three with those colors, also, yes he can use a 3x3x3 sequence to switch the 3 corners. (I have a 3x3x3 and a 5x5x5)

Answer (score 10):

I replicated your case on my 4x4x4:
[image]

This is an adjacent corner PLL parity case which can happen on even-layered cubes (like this 4x4x4, 6x6x6, 8x8x8, etc.)
Put green at the top and the two incorrect corners at the top-front (as in the picture above), and use the following algorithm ([**Here is an animation for this algorithm**](https://alg.cubing.net/?puzzle=4x4x4&alg=Uw2_Lw2_U2_l2L2_U2_Lw2_Uw2_F-_U-_F_U_F_R-_F2_U_F_U_F-_U-_F_R&setup=x_Uw2_Lw2_U2_l2L2_U2_Lw2_Uw2_F-_U-_F_U_F_R-_F2_U_F_U_F-_U-_F_R&view=playback)):

```
(Uu)2 (Ll)2 U2 l2 U2 (Ll)2 (Uu)2 F' U' F U F R' F2 U F U F' U' F R
```

where a capital letter is the outer later, and a lowercase letter is the inner layer (i.e. `Uu` is the top two layers; `l` is the inner left slide; etc.)

[Source including all 4x4x4 parity cases.](http://www.speedcubing.com/chris/4speedsolve3.html)

---

Why do parities happen on a 4x4x4 which aren't possible on a 3x3x3? I (Quuador) and some others explain that here in a recent question on the Cubers-reddit:
[What exactly causes 4x4 parities?](https://www.reddit.com/r/Cubers/comments/61c167/what_exactly_causes_4x4_parityies/)